# How to install Ubuntu 12 in place of Fedora 18 while preserving my dual boot windows 7 installation?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7, fedora

I have installed Win7 first, then I did install Fedora 18 and now I boot through the Fedora's boot loader to either of the systems.

What I want now is to replace Fedora 18 by Ubuntu 12 without breaking my windows installation (It would be critical not to break my windows at the moment; very sensitive timing)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be possible using the 12.10 installation disc.

during the installation process you will be prompted with a question with a few options to chose from. some of them are "ubuntu alongside Windows 7", one is "replace all". Chose the advanced option. here you will see your partitions.

Windows 7 will have (at least) 2 partitions, one of which has around 100 MB and one of size you specified when you installed windows 7 (or at some point after). It is important that you leave both of these untouched.

chose to remove partitions that belong to your Fedora install. This will remove any files stored under one those partitions, but Windows 7 will be left untouched.

then make a partiton for "/", and 1 for swap should you need hibernate or if you have a low amount of RAM.

when Ubuntu 12.10 is installed and you have rebooted you will get a grub 2 greeting screen, here you can chose from Ubuntu or Windows 7. This will come every time you reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to clone the Disk where you have your operrative systems installed using [clonezila](http://clonezilla.org/). 
After doing that, I would boot Ubuntu's Live CD, and use the GParted program to delete my Fedora partitions. Once the fedora partitions were deleted, I would then create a new partition for Ubuntu, using GParted as well. 
Then, I would just reboot and install Ubuntu.

If, by some reason, the installation got messed up, I would always be able to use clonezila and actually "go back in time" to the Windows + Fedora dual boot.